# Inno Setup constant for 'ProgramData' directory

Tags: inno-setup

I want my setup program to copy some files into the Windows `ProgramData` directory, I see that most Windows directories have pre-defined constants already defined in the Inno Setup documentation, however I can't see one for `ProgramData`.

Therefore I am planning to use something like:

```
{sd}\ProgramData\MyCompany\MyApp
```

Is this the correct/best way to deploy to this directory using Inno Setup? It just seems odd to me that there is no constant for the `ProgramData` directory.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's the [`{commonappdata}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=commonappdata).

---

It's named so, because historically (Windows XP) the path used to be `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data` (now that's a symbolic link to the `C:\ProgramData`).

---

And for the same reason, using the `{sd}\ProgramData` is not the correct way.